# Random shutdowns/access log

Tags: freeze, reboot, system, log

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop. All went well at first but now every once and awhile my system restarts or freezes. Usually it restarts. After it restarts there is a log that shows up just before the boot. The log says that there is a hardware issue and it appears its my cpu. Problem is that the log quickly disappears and then the system continues to boot normally. My question is: how do I access this log so I can find the issue?

Comment: check `sudo dmesg` or `tail -n 1000 /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: You can see the log entries just before the last crash with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. Read `man journalctl`.